# Column Name with the second highest value for each row

Tags: r, data.table

This is my data.frame/data.table

```
   library(data.table)
    df<- fread('

    A B C D SecondLargest
    1 3 2 4      B
    6 3 5 4      C
    7 3 7 1      A
    6 9 3 2      A
    ')
```

I am trying to extract the column name with second largest value(in parallel) in my "SecondLargest" desried column.

I have tried with no success.

```
 df[,SecondLargest:= colnames(df[,c(1:4),
with=FALSE])[apply(df[,c(1:4),with=FALSE],1,function(x) 
x[rank(1/x, ties.method='first')==2])]]
```

I am ok with both first or last type of tie breaker. You help is highly appreciated!

Comment: A base approach (assuming you don't yet have SecondLargest): `df$SecondLargest <- apply(df, 1, function(x){names(which(x == sort(x)[3]))[1]})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `melt`.  Here, I subset the dataset to remove the expected output, created a row number column 'rn', `melt` to 'long' format', `order` the 'value' in descending after grouping by 'rn', select the second element of 'variable' and assign (`:=`) it as "SecondLargest" column in 'df'.

```
df[, SecondLargest := melt(df[, -5, with = FALSE][, rn := 1:.N], id.var= 'rn')[, 
         variable[order(-value)][2] , rn]$V1]
df
#   A B C D SecondLargest
#1: 1 3 2 4             B
#2: 6 3 5 4             C
#3: 7 3 7 1             C
#4: 6 9 3 2             A
```

If we need the first tie,

```
melt(df[, -5, with = FALSE][, rn := 1:.N], id.var= 'rn')[, 
   variable[order(-value[!duplicated(value, fromLast=TRUE)])][2] , rn]$V1
#[1] B C A A
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How will this code break ties? first or last?

Comment: This is an awesome explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Very nice, but I am having difficulties breaking down your code.

Comment: @HermanToothrot  After removing the 5th column, create a sequence (`rn`), `melt` into 'long' format with id var as 'rn', order by the value, get the 2nd value of 'variable, grouped by 'rn' and use that to subset the dataset

Answer (score 1):

We could also do:

```
df$SecondLargest <- colnames(df)[apply(df,1,function(x)which(x==sort(x,partial=3)[3])[1])]

# A B C D SecondLargest
# 1 1 3 2 4             B
# 2 6 3 5 4             C
# 3 7 3 7 1             A
# 4 6 9 3 2             A
```

`partial` argument of `sort` is handful since it does not sort all elements but rather sorts partially based on what we need. `3 = ncol(df)-1` which means second largest.